# Where is the right place to configure SKScene content in SpriteKit?

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, skscene

Is it ok to configure (position sprites, add visible nodes etc) an SKScene's content in init method?

Where is the right place for such things: init? didMoveToView? something else?

Comment: Errr, yes. Do it wherever it works without issues.  But what are you really getting at? Your question is rather unspecific.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, all I want to know, is there any right method to use for scene initialization/configuration. Thats all :)

Comment: Init is for initializing, except where you can't. ;) For example self.view is nil on init so any setup code that needs the view has to be run in didMoveToView

Comment: @LearnCocos2D, so, if I don't use any UIKit views I can freely configure my SKScene in init method? But, if I want, for instance, to add UIButton the best place for that is didMoveToView method. Am I right?
If yes - please, post your comments as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**didMoveToView:** is called every time the scene is presented by an SKView.
Pros of positioning and adding sprites in didMoveToView: You can initialise many views without them grabbing a lot of memory. Cons: If you remove a view and then add it again didMoveToView: is called again. This means that you need to be sure to reset your scene in the beginning of didMoveToView: (only if you intend to remove and add again).

**init** is called when you initialise the SKScene. Pros of using init for positioning and adding sprites: It is only called once, and everything will be ready once you present it on  the scene. If you need to preload scenes for quick switching this might be handy. Cons: Each scene will take up the memory it needs to perform all the adding of sprites when init'ed and not when its shown.

Personally, I prefer to do everything in the **init** method.