# Sprite Kit, Grey background instead of image

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I can't seem to get my background to show the image.

Here is the code:

```
@implementation GameScene

 - (id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if ((self = [super initWithSize:size])) {

        self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);

        SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Background"];
        [self addChild:background];
    }
    return self;
}

@end

 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Configure the view.
    SKView * skView = (SKView *)self.view;
    skView.showsFPS = YES;
    skView.showsNodeCount = YES;
    /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
    skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = YES;

    // Create and configure the scene.
    GameScene *scene = [GameScene unarchiveFromFile:@"GameScene"];
    scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;

    // Present the scene.
    [skView presentScene:scene];
}
```

Comment: Is the all of the above code in your GameScene class?

Comment: Have you tried something like `skView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor]`?

Comment: sangony: The first code is in gamescene, the other one are in gameviewcontroller.

Linus G: What would that help? Sorry I'm pretty new at this.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is `initWithSize:` isn't actually called when you `unarchiveFromFile:` instead try using `didMoveToView:` in your scene.

```
-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    /* Setup your scene here */
    SKSpriteNode *background = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Background"];
    [self addChild:background];
}
```

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to @SkylerLauren answer instead of initWithSize:, you should use initWithCoder: method. More on this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29128718/3402095).

And if you explicitly want to use scene's init method you should be aware that self.view is nil while initialization.