# Scroll View in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, scroll, sprite-kit

I want to make a vertical scrolling view for the level selector on my SpriteKit game, I don't know if I have to use `UIScrollView` or make it using the SpriteKit framework. Please if anyone knows the best way to do it and how let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have several options here.

It is possible to integrate UI elements into SpriteKit, but instead of adding children to `self` (your scene), you would add subviews to `self.view`. You would of course, work with the view now instead of a scene so theres a different way of positioning elements which you would have to work out. Theres quite a few examples of how to do this, [here's one that might help you](http://www.boxesofbabies.com/tutorial/detail/2/Using-UIView-Elements-in-Sprite-Kit-Scenes).

An alternative is using something like [Scroll Kit](https://github.com/bobmoff/ScrollKit), which helps you integrate a UIScrollView into SpriteKit very conveniently!

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22279112/what-is-the-right-way-to-create-scrollable-table-in-skspritekit/22282102#22282102) which might be exactly what you're looking for. Hope this helps!