# How do I add a scrollView to my spriteKit project?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, uiscrollview, skspritenode

In a regular project, adding a scrollView is easy enough:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oQZ4mQpHXCo

But in a `spriteKit` project this approach doesn't work (as far as I know) since you can't add you nodes to the `UIView` (at least I didn't get it to work), resulting in a scrollable `view` on top of the nodes, rather than the nodes being in the scrollable view.

In my project I have several `nodes` drawn out as a game board with `tiles`. I would like to be able to scroll on all directions by dragging across the screen the direction I want to go.

I read this `SO` question and looked at the answer:

[Scroll View in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32000342/scroll-view-in-spritekit)

But there's a broken link that could perhaps be useful, and the `scrollKit` honestly seems a bit hard to grasp, even though I have played around with it a bit. So, what approach should I take? Is there some way I can use a UIScrollView in a `viewController` or is the scrollKit the way to go about this? And what about `touchesMoved`? Can this be used to scroll the screen? I also looked at this:

[ScrollView in SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40498345/scrollview-in-spritekit)

But don't seem to be able to get it to work properly.

Comment: Probably the most natural way to move the view around in SpriteKit is to have an SKCameraNode and have your various UI controls/gestures control that.  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skcameranode

Comment: Nice, I hadn't thought about that. Thanks for the tip!