# UIScrollView in SKScene

Tags: uiscrollview, sprite-kit, skscene

Why can't I see the text in the SKScene?
Is this the right way to have UIScrollView in SKScene?

```
-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize)size {
    if (self = [super initWithSize:size]) {

        UIScrollView * contentScrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        contentScrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        [contentScrollView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

        UITextView * mainContent = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
        mainContent.text = @"HELLO WORLD";
        mainContent.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        [contentScrollView addSubview:mainContent];
        [self.view addSubview:contentScrollView];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Take a look at this answer for further information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20800868/867635

Answer (score 5):

At this point (when initializing your scene with `-(id)initWithSize:(CGSize))` there is no view associated with your scene. If you want to add `UIScrollView` to your scene you should do it inside `-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView*)` method.

Also if you want your UIScrollView to contain SKNodes you might have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19096256/2328918

**EDIT 2014-04-20**

I have open sourced my component for panning and scrolling scenes in SpriteKit, please have a look at: https://github.com/pzbyszynski/PIOSpriteKit

Answer (score 0):

[ScrollKit](https://github.com/bobmoff/ScrollKit) can do spritekit in a scrollview.